# How to export file to excel 2007+ in C#

Tags: c#, excel, file, save

I want to export the file as an xls to Excel 2007+, why it is always saved as an Excel 97-2003 File?
what I do wrong?

this is the Row that saves the file:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(TargetFolderText.Text + "\\" + TargetFIleText.Text + ".xls");
```

Comment: have you tried saving it as an .xlsx

Comment: Take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769703/exporting-to-xlsx-using-microsoft-office-interop-excel-saveas-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you replace your code with:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(TargetFolderText.Text + "\\" + TargetFIleText.Text + ".xlsx");
```

The `xls` extension is for Excel 2003 and earlier.
The `xlsx` extension is for Excel 2007 and later.
Use `xlsm` when using macro's in Excel sheet(2007 and later)

Article about the differences between [XLS and XLSX](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-xls-and-xlsx/)

Comment: @user3365058 No problem, just a matter of 1 missing character:)