# I want to create xlsx (Excel) file from c#

Tags: c#, excel, cell, creation

This is a code which could create only create xls file. But I want to create xlsx (Excel) file; how can I do that from this code or else can I have another code which I could use to create xlsx files.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            if (xlApp == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
                return;
            }


            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "1";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "One";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "2";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Two";



            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\vdfgdfg.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file d:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting to .xlsx using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel SaveAs Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769703/exporting-to-xlsx-using-microsoft-office-interop-excel-saveas-error)

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/GemBox.Spreadsheet ? It is a component that doesnt require excel and there is a free licence for small sheets.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to know that the only thing you need to change in your code is `xlWorkBookNormal` to `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` and of course change your file name from `xls` to `xlsx` :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please try below updated code.

```
    public void CreateExcel()
    {
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        if (xlApp == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
            return;
        }


        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "1";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "One";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "2";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Two";

                  //Here saving the file in xlsx
                xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\vdfgdfg.xlsx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, misValue,
                misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);


        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file d:\\csharp-Excel.xlsx");
    }
```

Comment: i tried it once it dosent work it only save a xlsx file but cannot open it

Comment: Please try my updated code.It is working properly.It will save excel in **.XLSX** and will open it too.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the [NPOI](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi) library to create an Excel document. It doesn't require Office installed and doesn't use Interop / COM+. It also supports .NET Core.

```cs
using var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

int rowIndex = 0;

var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex++);
int cellIndex = 0;
row.CreateCell(cellIndex++).SetCellValue("ID");
row.CreateCell(cellIndex++).SetCellValue("Name");

var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex++);
cellIndex = 0;
row.CreateCell(cellIndex++).SetCellValue("1");
row.CreateCell(cellIndex++).SetCellValue("One");

var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex++);
cellIndex = 0;
row.CreateCell(cellIndex++).SetCellValue("2");
row.CreateCell(cellIndex++).SetCellValue("Two");


string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)!;
string xlsxPath = Path.Combine(path, $"vdfgdfg.xlsx");

using var fileStream = new FileStream(xlsxPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
workbook.Write(fileStream);
```

Links:

- NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI
- Quite good intro (HTTP!): http://www.independent-software.com/introduction-to-npoi.html
- Getting started: https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/wiki/Getting-Started-with-NPOI

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my [SwiftExcel](https://github.com/RomanPavelko/SwiftExcel) library. It was design for quick and easy excel output and what is more important - performance.

```
using (var ew = new ExcelWriter("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx"))
{
    ew.Write("ID", 1, 1);
    ew.Write("Name", 2, 1);

    ew.Write("1", 1, 2);
    ew.Write("One", 2, 2);

    ew.Write("2", 1, 3);
    ew.Write("Two", 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: Also it's under MIT license.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com). It is a library that creates xlsx files.

```
    ExcelDocument workbook = new ExcelDocument(1);

    // Set the sheet name
    workbook.easy_getSheetAt(0).setSheetName("Sheet1");

   // Add data
   ExcelTable xlsTable = ((ExcelWorksheet)workbook.easy_getSheetAt(0)).easy_getExcelTable();
   xlsTable.easy_getCell(0, 0).setValue("ID");
   xlsTable.easy_getCell(0, 1).setValue("Name");
   xlsTable.easy_getCell(1, 0).setValue("1");
   xlsTable.easy_getCell(1, 1).setValue("One");
   xlsTable.easy_getCell(2, 0).setValue("2");
   xlsTable.easy_getCell(2, 1).setValue("Two");

    // Create Excel file
    workbook.easy_WriteXLSXFile("d:\\vdfgdfg.xlsx");
```

See more at:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/create-excel-file.html

Answer (score 1):

Try **OpenXML** library, should do the trick, find more at

[Export DataTable to Excel with Open Xml SDK in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811143/export-datatable-to-excel-with-open-xml-sdk-in-c-sharp)

P.s. **Interop** won't work unless excel is installed on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace the following line:**

```
 xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\vdfgdfg.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

**with this line: `xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\vdfgdfg.xlsx");`**